# Use spring to load a text file where its location is defined as spring el

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-environment

In an spring base project, we want to load a file from `classpath` the file location must be evaluated from an `spring el` expression.

This feature is currently in spring which loads property files, the location can be any `Spring EL`.

```
<util:properties id="samplePolicy"
    location="classpath:/conf/#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}
              /sample.properties" />
```

This is exactly what we want but not to load a property file, just a text file.

So we try below:

We use `ResourceLoader`

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
//And then ....
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:myfile.txt");
```

How ever `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/conf/#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}}/sample.txt")` does not work.

It seems that the `resourceLoader.getResource` does not parse the Spring EL.

Although we can parse the EL and then get the file from resource loader, we wonder if it can be done easier, may be with some built in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that the resourceLoader.getResource does not parse the Spring EL.

The resource loader doesn't parse the SpEL, the application context does while it is being loaded.

Inject the value into a String field...

```
@Value("classpath:/conf/#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}/sample.txt")
private String location;
```

and

```
resourceLoader.getResource(this.location);
```